# Why the logs sent to syslog-ng are not saved?

Tags: python, docker, logging, python-logging, syslog-ng

I have an application which I run with `docker-compose`. Now I'd like to add logging to my application so I added this image to my compose -file:

```
syslog-ng:
    image: lscr.io/linuxserver/syslog-ng:latest
    container_name: syslog-ng
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - TZ=Europe/London
    volumes:
      - ./syslog-ng.conf:/config/syslog-ng.conf
      - /var/log/test_logs:/var/log
    ports:
      - 514:5514/udp
      - 601:6601/tcp
      - 6514:6514/tcp
    restart: unless-stopped
```

The `syslog-ng.conf` is located in the root of my repo, just like the `docker-compose.yaml`. This is the contents of the conf file, it is copied from [here](https://github.com/linuxserver/docker-syslog-ng/blob/main/root/defaults/syslog-ng.conf):

```
#############################################################################
# Default syslog-ng.conf file which collects all local logs into a
# single file called /var/log/booth_logs tailored to container usage.

@version: 3.35
@include "scl.conf"

source s_local {
  internal();
};

source s_network_tcp {
  syslog(transport(tcp) port(6601));
};

source s_network_udp {
  syslog(transport(udp) port(5514));
};

destination d_local {
  file("/var/log/test_logs");
  file("/var/log/test_logs-kv.log" template("$ISODATE $HOST $(format-welf --scope all-nv-pairs)\n") frac-digits(3));
};

log {
  source(s_local);
  source(s_network_tcp);
  source(s_network_udp);
  destination(d_local);
};
```

This is the service where the file `test_script.py` is located from where I try to send logs:

```
test_service:
    image: "another_service:latest"
    depends_on:
      - another_service
      - syslog-ng
    container_name: another_service
    volumes:
      - ./syslog-ng.conf:/config/syslog-ng.conf
    command: python app/test_script.py
```

And this is how I've been trying to test this in the `test_script.py``:

```
import logging
import logging.handlers

# configure the syslog handler
syslog = logging.handlers.SysLogHandler(address=('syslog-ng', 514))

# create a logger
logger = logging.getLogger('my_logger')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# add the syslog handler to the logger
logger.addHandler(syslog)

# use the logger
logger.debug('This is a debug message')
logger.info('This is an info message')
logger.warning('This is a warning message')
logger.error('This is an error message')
logger.critical('This is a critical message')
```

I don't get any errors and all the services are starting normally but no logs are saved. I've checked the container `/var/log` and my computers `/var/log/test_logs`. Any ideas what I'm missing here?

Comment: The typical Docker logging setup is for container processes to send their logs to stdout, where `docker logs` can retrieve them; if you do need to persist them somewhere else, the various log-aggregation systems tend to know how to collect the Docker logs and forward them to somewhere else.  Can you meet your higher-level requirements if you remove all of the syslog-related setup here?

Comment: @DavidMaze No, it would be important to me to be able to save logs locally in the host machine. I've understood this is completely doable and would suit my needs well.

Comment: Check if your test script can ping address 'syslog-ng' ?? Try with ip address?
You might need to manually create directory /var/log/test_logs